# netty error: InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io, netty

What's the correct idiom to send, receive and cast objects between client and server?  I'm starting from a simple example, I just want to send specific type between the client and server.

server output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:22 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRegistered
INFO: [id: 0xefbb5b05] REGISTERED
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:22 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler bind
INFO: [id: 0xefbb5b05] BIND(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:4454)
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:22 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelActive
INFO: [id: 0xefbb5b05, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:4454] ACTIVE
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:32 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler logMessage
INFO: [id: 0xefbb5b05, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:4454] RECEIVED: [id: 0xabdeec06, /127.0.0.1:59934 => /127.0.0.1:4454]
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:32 AM net.bounceme.dur.netty.ServerHandler exceptionCaught
SEVERE: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:32 AM net.bounceme.dur.netty.ServerHandler channelReadComplete
INFO: finished reading..?
^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/AgentServer$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/AgentServer$
```

client output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Jul 26, 2014 3:36:32 AM net.bounceme.dur.client.netty.ClientHandler channelActive
INFO: 

id  0
phone   0
title   null
state   undefined
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/AgentClient$
```

ServerHandler:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.jdbc.Title;

/**
 * Handles both client-side and server-side handler depending on which
 * constructor was called.
 */
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServerHandler.class.getName());
    private RecordsQueueWrapper q = null;

    public ServerHandler(RecordsQueueWrapper q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object obj) {
        Title receivedTitle = (Title) obj;
        log.info(receivedTitle.toString());
        Title nextTitle = q.pop();
        ctx.write(nextTitle);
        log.info("..channelRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        log.info("finished reading..?");
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.severe(cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

ClientHandler:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client.netty;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.jdbc.Title;

public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName());

    public ClientHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Title firstTitle = new Title();
        log.info(firstTitle.toString());
        ctx.writeAndFlush(firstTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        try {
            Title t = (Title) msg;
            log.info(msg.toString());
            ctx.write(t);
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {  //????
            log.warning(cce.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx
    ) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause
    ) {
        log.severe(cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassResolvers;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import net.bounceme.dur.jdbc.Title;

public final class Server {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyProps p = new MyProps();
        int port = p.getServerPort();
        RecordsQueueWrapper q = new RecordsQueueWrapper();
        q.init(99);
        new Server().startServer(port, false, q);
    }

    private void startServer(int port, boolean ssl, final RecordsQueueWrapper q) throws CertificateException, SSLException, InterruptedException {
        final SslContext sslCtx;
        if (ssl) {
            SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
            sslCtx = SslContext.newServerContext(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey());
        } else {
            sslCtx = null;
        }
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            if (sslCtx != null) {
                                p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                            }
                            p.addLast(
                                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                                    new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.weakCachingConcurrentResolver(Title.class.getClassLoader())),
                            //new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                            new ServerHandler(q)
                            );
                        }
                    });

            b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client.netty;

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassResolvers;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.jdbc.Title;

/**
 * Modification of {@link EchoClient} which utilizes Java object serialization.
 */
public final class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
    static final int SIZE = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("size", "256"));

    public Client() {
    }

    public void init() throws InterruptedException, SSLException {
        MyProps p = new MyProps();
        String host = p.getHost();
        int port = p.getServerPort();
        startClient(host, port, false);
    }

    private void startClient(final String host, final int port, final boolean SSL) throws SSLException, InterruptedException {
        // Configure SSL.
        final SslContext sslCtx;
        if (SSL) {
            sslCtx = SslContext.newClientContext(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);
        } else {
            sslCtx = null;
        }

        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            if (sslCtx != null) {
                                p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port));
                            }
                            p.addLast(
                                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                                    //new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                                    new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.weakCachingConcurrentResolver(Title.class.getClassLoader())),
                                    new ClientHandler());
                        }
                    });

            // Start the connection attempt.
            b.connect(host, port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

see also:

[Strange Netty error whilst deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249800/strange-netty-error-whilst-deserializing)

Comment: Is Title Serializable ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer yes, Title `implements Serializable` and `serialVersionUID` has a value.  I think it's probably something to do with `ChannelHandler`, ie, somehow initiate the ping-pong from **outside** the `Client` and `ClientHandler`, perhaps in another class.  However, I don't know the netty mechanism to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please check package of Title object, there are not must be different package name, in server and in client! For example: in server com.server.dto and in client com.server.dto!